# Is there a way to feed in different values from a table to Cucumber background? Make background dynamic?

Tags: java, automation, cucumber, ios-ui-automation, cucumber-java

I have a Feature file and the background step is pretty simple. However, the setup done in that step needs to be working with two different types of values and it is applicable to all the scenarios within that FF. Is there a way we can make this background dynamic?

Example: I want to do as below:

```
Background:
Given hospital configuration is done using '<some config>'
|some config|
| abc       |
|xyz        |
```

Comment: so basically you want to run every feature in that feature file twice. Once with config abc and the second time with config xyzzy

Comment: @diabolist yes, correct!

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways I can think of to run a feature file twice, one with one configuration and the other with another configuration.

1. Duplicate the feature file and change the background so that it specifically loads the particular configuration.

Before dismissing this solution look at some of the positives.

- its very simple
- its easy to document (just put comments in the preamble about the duplication)
- it supports customization specific to a particular profile.

The last point is worth expanding on. If the behavior is identical with each profile then what is the point of the profile. Basically you are saying it has no effect at all. If it has not effect at all then why are you testing it. If the behavior varies between profiles then you really want to explore and express those differences.

2. Run the feature twice by using an external setting.

This basically comes down to having Cucumber pull the setting from the environment and running cucumber twice, once for the first setting, and then again for the second setting.

So something like

```
SETTING=abc cucumber ...  
SETTING=xyz cucumber ...
```

3. Use an around hook to run the internals of a scenario twice.

Here you are putting a tag on the feature and making a custom hook to run the scenarios twice. This is equivalent to the second solution but you are embedding the mechanism inside a single run of the features.

In ruby this would look something like

```
# run_twice_hook.rb

Around(@run_twice) do |scenario, block|
  load_first_setting
  block.call
  load_second_setting
  block.call
end
```

I think this solution comes closest to what the OP wants.

I also think this is the worst solution, because its technical, tricky, hidden and embedded inside the feature run. Its expensive to implement and expensive to maintain, and it probably hides an underlying business problem (mentioned in the first solution)

So please use this solution with a great deal of caution. In general with cuking simple is best, and a bit of repetition is preferable to technical complexity to avoid repetition.